# How to manage PATH variable in Windows?

Tags: windows, system, classpath

Every time I experiment with a new language, compiler, interpreter, tool, or whatever, and I want to run that from the command line, I would have to go to System and change my PATH variable. However, the box to put the monster string in consists of only a 1-line text box. I frequently find myself having to copy/paste the PATH string into Notepad just to edit it -- It's already over half a page. Right now I've counted about 30 different path URL's.

Is there a better way to manage paths than to squeeze all of them into one string? I'm thinking of using SUSE for development since my PATH is so messed up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you always start the command line from one or a few shortcuts, you can run a batch file when it starts. For example:

```
cmd /k autoexec_console.cmd
```

where the batch file could have

```
set path=c:\foo;%path%
```

or anything else, and this would persist only for that cmd.exe instance.

---

XP's [Service Pack 2 Support tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en) (looks like there's [one for SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=673a1019-8e3e-4be0-ac31-70dd21b5afa7&DisplayLang=en), but it doesn't say what's in it) comes with a program `setx.exe` that works like a permanent `set`.

Answer (score 10):

There is a really nice freeware environment editor available called [RapidEE](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about)

**Rapid Environment Editor**

Rapid Environment Editor (RapidEE) is an environment variables editor.

It includes an easy to use GUI and replaces the small and inconvenient Windows edit box.

RapidEE 8.x supports Windows XP, 2003, Vista, 2008, Windows 7, Windows 8 & Windows 10 (including 64-bit versions).

If you still use Windows NT or 2000, then use version 6.1. For Windows 9x or ME use version 2.1.

Features

- **Editable tree**: Show environment variables and values as an editable tree.
- **Portable mode**: RapidEE doesn't require installation and could be run as a "portable application".
- **Error checking**: Automatically checking for invalid pathnames and filenames
- **Multilanguage interface**: RapidEE is translated into a number of languages (English, Russian, Japanese, French, Polish, German, Italian, Latvian, Slovak, Greek, Spanish, Chinese, Dutch, Swedish, Korean, Croatian, Danish, Brazilian Portuguese, Finnish, Norwegian, Indonesian, Romanian, Hungarian, Turkish, Abkhazian, Ukrainian, Czech, Arabic), and the language can be changed on the fly.

Comment: I needed to modify my system PATH which is a long mess of course, and this tool made that very easy. Different path components were separately editable, etc.

Answer (score 8):

To better mange very long PATH in the default windows interface, you can have variable evaluated into variables :

```
SDKPATH -> some_sdk_path; some_more_sdk_paths; some_more_sdk_paths;
DEVPATH -> some_dev_path; some_more_dev_paths; %SDKPATH%
PATH    -> some_common_path; some_mode_paths; %DEVPATH%
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're just experimenting with a one-shot language you can create a small startup batch file which manipulates the path:

```
set PATH=C:\My\New\Language\bin;%PATH%
```

and create a small testing environment by creating a shortcut to

```
cmd /k mybatch.cmd
```

where the path will be set to your liking. Otherwise you can edit the long string in the registry which may be slightly better than a 200px wide textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Use a batch (.BAT) file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to try [Environment variables editor](http://eveditor.com) (Eveditor). It is easy to use and completely free.

Environment variables editor helps you organize and streamline your use of system variables (including System PATH) and optimize your work environment without risk of losing valuable configuration settings, something that can happen inadvertently and with devastating effect when you install new software on your machine.